# Недвижимое имущество. Есть ли множественное число?

Tags: грамотная-речь, множественное-число

*Недвижимое имущество* во множественном числе будет *недвижимые имущества*?

Answer (score 2):

Недвижимое имущество — (недвижимость) — термин ГК (Закона № 122-ФЗ, НК), который не имеет формы множественного числа. Вне этого кодекса ранее — сто и более лет назад — и в наше время публикаций с формой мн. числа предостаточно.

*Имущества суть недвижимые или движимые. Недвижимыми имуществами признаются по закону земли и всякие угодья, дома, заводы, фабрики, лавки, всякие строения и пустые дворовые места , а также железные дороги» (ср. Общ. Уст. Жел. Дорог., изд. 1886 г., ст. 138).*

Из Энциклопедии Брокгауза и Ефрона: *«В составе Недвижимых имуществ закон отличает имущества раздельные и нераздельные.*

Словарь склонений http://sklonenie.gramatik.ru/nedvijimost даёт склонение по падежам во мн. числе также, как и единственном.

Comment: *Словарь склонений дает* ну они там много чего дают, даже самые неожиданные формы. Там принцип Зализняка: все что можно образовать по общей парадигме - все приводится, нормативность не рассматривается. А вот найти бы пример реального современного использования.

Comment: В «Гражданско-правовом режиме недвижимости» (Великомыслов Ю.Я. //Allpravo.Ru – 2005) не найти употребления мн. ч. от НЕДВИЖИМОСТЬ, как и в других современных законодательных документах (употребляется термин «недвижимые вещи»), но есть цитата: «Нет необходимости, чтобы юридическое деление имуществ на недвижимые и движимые совпадало с физическою неподвижностью или подвижностью вещей: в области права это деление имуществ имеет то значение, что одни определения связываются с имуществами недвижимыми, другие — с имуществами движимыми...».

Comment: О! Вот это пойдет как прецедент.

Answer (score 2):

Низзя, легче застрелиться! И долой с корабля современности проклятый канцелярит!

Рассказывает Справка Грамоты.ру:

**[Вопрос № 209328](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20209328)**

> Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли форма множественного
>   числа словосочетания "недвижимое имущество". Если я хочу осмотреть
>   несколько объектов недвижимости, могу ли я сказать "несколько
>   недвижимых имуществ" или "несколько недвижимостей" (по аналогии
>   осмотреть несколько квартир). Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Слова *недвижимость* и *имущество* во множественном числе не
>   употребляются. Поэтому оба варианта неверны.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от контекста.
В бытовом языке множественного числа у сочетания нет (о чем и поведала "Справка", в очередной раз выдав личное мнение за абсолютную истину). 
Но если текст юридический, нотариальный и тому подобное, то множественное существует де-факто. Правда, в основном у слова *недвижимость* - "недвижимости", "недвижимостей". "Имущества", "имуществ" - это язык скорее прошлой эпохи.

Тем не менее форму "недвижимые имущества" стоит признать возможной, примеры - у shampar.

//---

Да, я не сказал, что при использовании множественного речь идет не о объектах недвижимого имущества, а именно о разных "имуществах" - разных лиц, например. Или как в примере у shampar - о разных типах.