# Употребление слова "имущество" во множественном числе

Tags: множественное-число

Можно ли употреблять словосочетание "недвижимое имущество" во множественном числе "недвижимые имущества. Например в предложении: **Сторонам известно, что вышеуказанные недвижимые имущества обременены ипотекой**.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434263/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be

Comment: @Рузана И ещё вот здесь: Можно ли писать недвижимые имущества?  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30454/Можно-ли-писать-недвижимые-имущества. Возможно, вопрос стоит закрыть? Вопрос задавал тот же участник. Недвижимое имущество. Есть ли множественное число?

Comment: Господа, здесь у вас спрашивают о конкретном предложении.

Comment: Я думаю, для оценки конкретного случая требуется широкий контекст.